# How to play dropbox video on mobile website?

Tags: video, video-streaming, dropbox, mobile-website

I have a mobile website which basically displays you the dropbox contents. Now I want the user to be able to play the video files also on the mobile itself without actually downloading the file.

Its basically playing from the web url instead of streaming from a database.

Is there any player for that? Or any way to achieve that? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API allows you to get a "media" URL for a file in Dropbox. This URL will work for up to four hours and supports range requests, so it works well for streaming a video. I'm not sure which platform you're developing on, so I can't tell you the exact code, but here's the documentation for the HTTP endpoint: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media.